# &amp;#039; issues in titles (Joomla) & how it renders in Facebook

Tags: joomla, title, meta, joomla-k2

Hello I use Joomla as CMS with a plugin (K2) to handle my articles. Right now all the meta titles are outputting this &#039; when there is an apostrophe, and Facebook posts render like this

Canada's Economic Action Plan: A Breakdown.

I think what is happening is that the title is being filtered twice, giving the double code for apostrophes. That's what I think but I don't know. Have a look at this page source for the title

http://www.thebeaverton.com/local/local-in-brief/item/360-teacher-compares-death-of-kindergartners-puppy-to-divorce-from-kathy

and you will see

```
<pre> meta name="title" content="Teacher compares death of kindergartner&amp;#039s    puppy to divorce from Kathy" </pre>
```

What the heck can I do to stop this? I get all my visitors from Facebook shares so this is terrible. Thank you.

Comment: Post this on K2 - I've noticed this on our site since we upgraded to version 2.6 although I've not been hugely fussed about it - although it is something I've been meaning to look into. If your desperate try dropping back to K2 v 2.5.8. What version of k2 are you on out of interest?

Answer (score 0):

Update your k2 version to the latest (2.6.2) this bug - I think introduced in k2 v2.6. Has been fixed in this version! Hope this helps!!

Comment: Hi George, thanks for the reply, but as far as I can tell the latest K2 is 2.6.2 which is the one I am using and the issue isn't addressed by any K2 threads on their community board. It musn't be a big deal to change the code on this issue, if only I knew where to start. I imagine the problem hasn't been reported a lot but for me it's quite bad, no one clicks on a FB post that's full of html characters. Makes it look spammy.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to add a Description in the Metadata Information tab (K2 Edit Item) for any K2 items with special characters which will override the default handling and provide control over how it appears in FB